# VB .NET Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.... but im updating not inserting?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

Inherited a vb .net web forms page. SQL Server database.

THE CODE ISNT SHOWING A FIELD ADD - First, before running the below code , I add a 'myfield' to a table named 'mytable' in SQL server management studio. Then when I run the code that was working before the add, I receive the following error...

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

...on the line where sql2.executeNonQuery() runs in the code below (yes, I am aware that this is not protected from injection):

*un is declared and populated prior to this code executing and is not the reason why the code is failing.

```
Protected Sub Test()
    Dim str As String
    Dim con2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString)
    str = "update mytable set mydate = GetDate() where myfield = '" & un & "'"
    con2.Open()
    Dim sql2 As New SqlCommand(str, con2)
    sql2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con2.Close()
End Sub
```

I've seen this error before with insert into statements formed badly or with select lists, and that's the common answer on stack overflow, but none of the help I can find online references this happening in update statements, only inserts.

Here is connection string information from web.config. I thought to look at it too since its being used in the code, but it doesn't look like anything is out of place:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAMEHERE;Initial Catalog=DBNAMEHERE;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

So on to the question(s):

Are there any other configuration files somewhere that I may not be aware of that may contain some sort of table definition that isn't catching the new SQL field add?

*Or*

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Thank you in advance and please let me know if I can provide any more information that may be helpful.

Comment: Where is table name?You are using keyword `table` as tablename

Comment: Sorry, due to company data policies, I changed field and table names around.... ill fix it so its not using a keyword. That is not the actual table name.

Comment: what is the type of the myfield?

Comment: VARCHAR(50) allows nulls

Comment: @ogg130 it seems your table has foreign keys as well, better is take the text from debug mode and try to execute it on server and check the result

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, have never had to go there so I will attempt it.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting error  this code only? Did you try to debug?

Comment: This error actually cropped up in another place as well. It was for an insert into statement that was using a select statement for its values rather than an explicit list. I corrected that, and this is the next error that came down the chain, however this time I cant correct it in code the way  I did with the insert into statement. I have not had a lot of experience with the debugger yet, so it sounds like now's the time to learn :D

Comment: You say "When I use SQL to add a field to a table named 'mytable'" but the code you've posted is `update` code. adding a field is `ALTER TABLE` Is the code you've posted the one that throws the error? Do you have any triggers in your database?

Comment: No triggers, the  database is very simple. This code is not adding a field. The field is added and this code that I supply breaks after the field is added. The field add is not represented in this code.